# if element in sight, do something

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a slider. It animates things inside of layers. It also animates layers. So; what i want is when video layer comes sight, and it animates video itself from out of slider area; i need to do something.

This is what i have done so far. But it doesn't work.

```
if ($(".homeBannerVideoBg").live().is(":inView")) {
    $("body").addClass("YEEHA");
}
else {
    $("body").addClass("VUUHUU");
}
```

homeBannerVideoBg is my video element.

Can i get a hand over here ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `live()` :<

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

There's a great plugin, for determining when an element comes into the view when the user scrolls through the page. It takes the form of an event, so you can use a callback to perform your actions, just as you would a "click"

Answer (score 0):

try `:visible`

```
   if ($(".homeBannerVideoBg").is(":visible")) { 
        $("body").addClass("YEEHA"); 
   } 
   else { 
        $("body").addClass("VUUHUU"); 
   }
```

Comment: He is probably looking for a callback in the animations

Comment: No it is visible alredy. I need to control the element that stands inside of an overflow hidden div.

Comment: Every element without `display: none` would return true on this test. It does not check if an element is in the viewport or not, which the OP is asking.

Comment: @OptimusCrime my first comment was about this.