# Animate a div with jquery when we scroll to its position

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am need of a jquery functionality through which when user is scrolling the page and a certain div comes in visible portion/middle of the screen some action happens. For example: Verelo.com. If you scroll down you will see a glob with two icons along with and an jquery animation with black arrows. I need similar functionality. I don't expect exact but at least something to be nearest.

For my efforts, I found this example : Verelo.com and did some googling. But didn't find anything yet.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

They listen to the document's `scroll` event, and calculate the document's `scrollTop` compared to the element's position.

Basically, the parameters you'll need to consider in order to calculate whether or not an element is in viewport (taking only Y-axis scroll into consideration), is the document's scroll position, the height of the viewport, the position of the target element, and the height of the target element.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

   var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
   var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

   var targetPosition = $('#target').position().top;
   var targetHeight = $('#target').outerHeight();

   // viewport stretches from scrollTop to (scrollTop + viewportHeight)

});
```

You'll also need to figure out if `.position().top` or `.offset().top` is most suitable for you, depending on how the element is positioned, and on what it is that is being scrolled.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wznp/)

Comment: @Deepak: you do, hey? I was merely trying to explain the process. Well, answers's updated with some more code and a demo.

Comment: Great!!!..+1..Works like a charm. One more question. Basically, I have 4 images. Now what I want that when the div comes into focus, each image should animate after a certain of amount. For example: I have A.jpg, B.jpg, C.Jpg. Now when I scroll the page and the div is in foucs, First of the A.jpg should animate than B.jpg and then C.jpg. I think some settimeout function function or something like that can work. But one more thing is that it should animate once.

Comment: @Deepak: jQuery `.animate` animates only once, unless you instruct it otherwise, and it accepts a callback which you could use to trigger sequential animations; the first animation being initiated, of course, from the scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question here haha, [if element in sight, do something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031724/if-element-in-sight-do-something/11031796#11031796)

The plugin located here, https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview, gives you a trigger you can bind to, to determine when an element is in view

Answer (score 0):

What you can do do is, analyze the source of this file http://www.verelo.com/js/themeFunctions.js from their site, it's not minified so You can dig how they are doing this:

Here's the list of necessary functions from that js file

```
$(window).scroll(function scrollDetection() {
                scrollLogic();
                });
```

So `scrollLogic();` is being called when window is scrolled. Now whats in `scrollLogic();` function. I am adding only the necessary part of it as it is big

```
function scrollLogic(){
    //If page is scrolled further than 100%, drop navigation menu from top and do a dance. Preferably an Irish River dance of sorts
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > howItWorksPosition) {
        window.sliderTimerOn = 'false';
        clearInterval(intervalId);

        if( $(window).scrollTop() > howItWorksPosition && $(window).scrollTop() < featuresPosition) {btnClick('.howItWorks'); executeScene(); window.ourCustomersFrame = 'false';}
.......
}
```

`howItWorksPosition` has been calculated before using

```
    howItWorksOffset = $('#howItWorks').offset();
howItWorksPosition = howItWorksOffset.top -180;
```

They are calling `executeScene();` when window is scrolled up to that div and `executeScene();` is doing the animation. You can check `executeScene();` to find how they are doing the animation.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin do exactly this for you:

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) {
    // do stuff
}, { offset: 50 })
```

in above example handler function runs when top of the element is 50px from the top of the viewport. you can check if user is scrolling 'down' or 'up' with direction parameter.

for more advanced options and examples see [jquery waypoints docs page](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs).